# Obtain observations based on percentile value in python pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, pandas, percentile

I have a data frame in the following form:

```
d1 = {'City_ID': ['City_1','City_1','City_1','City_1','City_2','City_3','City_3','City_3','City_3','City_3'], 
'Indiv_ID': ['Indiv_1','Indiv_2','Indiv_3','Indiv_4','Indiv_5','Indiv_6','Indiv_7','Indiv_8','Indiv_9','Indiv_10'],
'Expenditure_by_earning': [0.11, 0.66, 0.51, 0.43, 0.46,0.8, 0.14, 0.06, 0.64, 0.95]}
```

The real dataset contains over a 1000 cities with multiple individuals although some cities contain only 1 observation. I would like to obtain individuals across each city whose expenditure by earning value is less than the 25% percentile and greater than 75% percentile for that city.

The output in this case I would expect:

```
City_ID     Indiv_ID    Expenditure_by_earning     Percentile
City_1      Indiv_1          0.11                      25
City_1      Indiv_2          0.66                      75
City_3      Indiv_7          0.06                      25
City_3      Indiv_8          0.14                      25
City_3      Indiv_6          0.8                       75
City_3      Indiv_10         0.95                      75
```

Note: City 2 gets eliminated.

Would someone help me on how to achieve this using python?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Calculate quantiles by city (result is indexed by city)
q25 = d1.groupby('City_ID')['Expenditure_by_earning'].quantile(.25)
q75 = d1.groupby('City_ID')['Expenditure_by_earning'].quantile(.75)

# Calculate Residuals Above Percentile Levels
# (First set d1 Index on CityID (like q25/q75), allowing for direct subtraction)
d1 = d1.set_index('City_ID')
d1['Pct_75_resid'] = d1['Expenditure_by_earning'] - q75
d1['Pct_25_resid'] = d1['Expenditure_by_earning'] - q25

# Filter
d1.query('Pct_75_resid >= 0 or Pct_25_resid <=0')
```

Comment: Awesome. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df

    City_ID Expenditure_by_earning  Indiv_ID
0   City_1  0.11    Indiv_1
1   City_1  0.66    Indiv_2
2   City_1  0.51    Indiv_3
3   City_1  0.43    Indiv_4
4   City_2  0.46    Indiv_5
5   City_3  0.80    Indiv_6
6   City_3  0.14    Indiv_7
7   City_3  0.06    Indiv_8
8   City_3  0.64    Indiv_9
9   City_3  0.95    Indiv_10

df = df.merge(df.groupby('City_ID')['Expenditure_by_earning'].quantile([0.25, 0.75]).unstack(), left_on='City_ID', right_index=True)
df.loc[((df['Expenditure_by_earning']<=df[0.25]) | (df['Expenditure_by_earning']>=df[0.75])) & (df[0.25]!=df[0.75])]


City_ID Expenditure_by_earning  Indiv_ID    0.25    0.75
0   City_1  0.11    Indiv_1 0.35    0.5475
1   City_1  0.66    Indiv_2 0.35    0.5475
5   City_3  0.80    Indiv_6 0.14    0.8000
6   City_3  0.14    Indiv_7 0.14    0.8000
7   City_3  0.06    Indiv_8 0.14    0.8000
9   City_3  0.95    Indiv_10    0.14    0.8000
```